# How do I find vertical asymptotes of this function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

$$
f(x) = 4\tan(\pi x)
$$

I am having trouble finding the asymptotes for this problem.
From what I gathered the asymptotes of $\tan(x)$ occur at $x=\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi$.

How would I solve this using what I know? (answer not required, I would just like help on the next steps!).

Comment: You mean $x = \pi / 2 + n \pi$, not $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication of $\pi$ on the inside shrinks the graph horizontally by a factor of $\pi$, so the new asymptotes occur at $\frac{1}{\pi}$ of the old ones; that is, at

$$x = \frac{1}{\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi\right) = \frac{1}{2} + n$$

On the other hand, the vertical scaling by a factor of $4$ does not affect the asymptotes.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. I definitely need to study up on my pre-calc again.